# relative path changed issue when my app is launched from another app

Tags: c++, qt

I face a confused issue, I have an app(let's named A.exe), in my app, it can launch another app(B.exe),  in my folder , A.exe and B.exe are in the same folder, so here the relative path of B.exe is "B.exe".

However, now another app(C.exe) can run the A.exe, C.exe is in another folder, so here comes the issue, if A.exe is launched from C.exe, it can never run the C.exe, as I get a error says it can't find C.exe.

So I think the relative path changed to current C.exe's folder, in C.exe folder, there is no B.exe.

Is any friends get this issue? or how can I get the right relative path in different state to fix this issue?

I use ShExecInfo to run my the c.exe, some code is as following:

```
QStringList paramList;
paramList.push_back("requiresAdmin");
QString paramsAsOneString = paramList.join(' ');
LPCWSTR szParams = reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(paramsAsOneString.utf16());
LPCWSTR szAppName = reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(appName.utf16());

SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = { 0 };
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = L"runas";
ShExecInfo.lpFile = szAppName;
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = szParams;
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;
```

Comment: You should get full path of `A.exe` (using `GetModuleFileNameW`) and replace `A.exe` at the end with `B.exe`.

Comment: cool, I solve it by using full path, thanks guy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you launch an app from another app, you have to set up the folder too. I mean, if C is in PATH_C, and C launch the app A that is in the PATH_A, the process A run in the PATH_C, so when you try to run the process B, its not accesible.

You have to set up the folder too, for example. When you run nautilus in Ubuntu, you have to setup the folder too:

```
  user:~Documents/$: nautilus /home/user/
```

If so, nautilus is opened in the given folder. If not, nautilus is opened in the folder of the process that launch it, in this case Documents folder.

To avoid the problem, if B.exe its allways in the same folder as A.exe, then use the relative path of the executable file to launch B.exe, by using [GetModuleFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Comment: very useful for me , different is that  I use QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()  to get the absolute path, thanks very much, my  friend.